# c++ projects depending on sorting and search algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, sorting

I've been trying to study datastrucutres and algorithms for many times and I feel everytime that I'm spending time on the theoretical part.
I wanted to know if there are some common famous projects to implement that mainly depend on sorting and search algorithms using C++ in order to practice more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), i.e. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) etc. Any spell checker, though searching there is rather different and is based on string similarity algorithms (like [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)). There are also [open-source search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Open_source_search_engines). They do all sort of things - similarity, semantics analysis, data collection, search etcetera. Some of the interesting C++ projects in this regard is Google's [Spare Hash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) - a collection of amazing hash tables. In other words - sorting and searching is everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

One interview question i was given was about a data structure of names, such as a phone book.

Which would be the best data structure, and which sorting & searching methods would be best if:

- You commonly search for one name at a time...or,
- You commonly print out all the names in a row...or,
- You commonly search for names when you don't know the full name, such as only first, or only last
- etc.